# QGIS 3.14 : Inserting into Oracle database does not work when metadata is set with three dimensions

Tags: oracle, qgis

I´m trying to set up an Oracle Connection from QGIS. The tables are set with metadata for Three dimensions in Oracle. When I try to add objects to the database, however, I get the following error:

```
Oracle error while adding features: Oracle error: Could not insert feature -27
SQL: ORA-29875: failed in the execution of the ODCIINDEXINSERT routine
ORA-13364: layer dimensionality does not match geometry dimensions
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_INDEX_METHOD_10I", line 976
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_INDEX_METHOD_10I", line 488
Unable to execute statement
```

When I remove the Z-dimension from the metadata it seems to work. Any help on what can resolve the problem is appreciated.

The Z-value is usually added by convention at the organization and not always used, i.e. set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

ironic, I was actually having a similar error today when attempting to save data into a geopackage. (That is, i don't get the error on insert, i get it when hitting save).
I got a slightly different error:
'QGIS error creating feature -16: failed to prepare SQL: INSERT INTO..... etc.
However my error was related to the fact that the geometry attribute name had somehow been created as 'geom'....and the GDAL code is looking for a geometry attribute called 'geometry'.
I recreated my geopackage table, with the attribute named 'geometry' and z values, and no more problems, (even if source data has no z).

however I don't think this is your problem - it could be that source data doesn't have a z - You could try maybe setting a procedure somewhere or derived field, such that z value is populated upon insert.
The error code makes it sounds like either the source has no z value (ie: Geometry dimensions) or the layer indexing is not setup to handle z (ie: ODCIINDEXINSERT routine layer dimensionality).
That may be the starting point for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! In my case I had to remove the z-value from the metadata table to stop getting the error. Not the best solution, but the z-value was not needed.